Do FIDE or any of the federations rate Lightning chess?
Lightning chess predates digital clocks by many decades. It is basically 0+10s delay chess. A buzzer goes off every 10 seconds and the player on move has to move on the buzzer. The Scottish chess federation has even gone so far as to publish its rules for Lightning chess.
Most of the clubs I've played for have had a lightning tournament at the end of the regular season as a bit of fun and as far as I know the question of having the games rated has never occurred. I guess its 0+10d time control means that if it were rated it would qualify, just, as blitz.
Do any federations rate lightning?

It should've been called buzzer or metronome chess.

FWIW, the US Chess Federation doesn't consider any time control of less than 5 minutes to be ratable (or more accurately, the base time plus number of seconds of delay or increment must be at least 5 - so 3+2 would be ratable too, in the USCF "Blitz" rating system).
